# Basic iphone app, and breaking point error

Tags: ios6

I'm trying to learn ios coding and trying to make a foodDiary application.. I've used empty project file and then added the storyboard,view controller and table view controller

when I run my program the tableView Menu shows up with the elements in it, then when I press the + button a view controller shows up which has a textfield and a button inside.. when I type in something and press the button my program crushes and I get breakpoint error,
I get error here:

```
    - (IBAction)addFoodButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *newFood = [addFoodText text];

    [foodTableViewController addFood:newFood];

    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

my partial coding are:

**DAYfoodTableViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

@interface DAYfoodTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *foodArray;

-(void) addFood:(NSString *) newFood;

@end

**DAYfoodTableViewController.m**

```
    #import "DAYfoodTableViewController.h"
#import "DAYaddFoodViewController.h"
@interface DAYfoodTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation DAYfoodTableViewController
@synthesize foodArray;

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    DAYaddFoodViewController *addFoodViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    [addFoodViewController setFoodTableViewController:self];
}

-(void) addFood:(NSString *)newFood
{
    [foodArray addObject:newFood];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    foodArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Pizza",@"Chips",@"Sandwiches",@"Hot Dogs", nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [foodArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    int rowNumber=[indexPath row];

    NSString *food=[foodArray objectAtIndex:rowNumber];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:food];


    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [foodArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]  ];


        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade ];

        /*
          or (by asim)

         if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
         [foodArray removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]  ];

         [[self tableView] reloadData];
         }

         */
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     */
}

@end
```

**DAYaddFoodTableViewController.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DAYfoodTableViewController.h"
@interface DAYaddFoodViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) DAYfoodTableViewController *foodTableViewController;

- (IBAction)addFoodButton:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *addFoodText;

@end
```

**DAYaddFoodTableView.m**

```
#import "DAYaddFoodViewController.h"


@interface DAYaddFoodViewController ()


@end

@implementation DAYaddFoodViewController

@synthesize foodTableViewController;
@synthesize addFoodText;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)addFoodButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *newFood = [addFoodText text];

    [foodTableViewController addFood:newFood];

    [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
@end
```

The weird thing is that when the program crushes and I re-run the program through the simulator it works perfectly..
 what could cause this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the partial code listing that you didn't finish all of the tasks required. You have made your initial controller to be a delegate, but not defined the delegate as a property in your header file or synthesized it in your implementation file. Additionally, you did not add it to the second controller, but are attempting to call the optional method of your first controller, and calling it incorrectly. I think that is why it is crashing.
Seques, which you've used, coupled with notifications, can accomplish many of the things which delegation can.
You need to study up on notification and seques... which allows you to pass data back and forth between controllers. And, in your case you need to.
Watch the appropriate WWDC videos, and work through some tutorials, and these are some of the best... http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials